# Is there a more efficient method to find dupes in Sql server

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5, linq-to-objects

I have this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450329/possible-to-write-a-join-between-sql-and-datatable-using-linq/4454871#4454871) for which I provided *a* solution. However, I don't feel that is as efficient as it could be:

```
using (DataContext context = new DataContext(SqlConnection)
{
    var custInfo = context.GetTable<tbl_CustomerInfo>();

    string compID = ImportCust.Rows[0]["CompanyID"].ToString();

    var imports = from cust in ImportCust.AsEnumerable()
                  select cust.Field<int>("CustomerID");

    var dupes = from import in imports
                join cust in custInfo
                on import equals cust.CustomerID 
                where cust.CompanyID== pivnum
                select cust;

    var records = dupes.GetEnumerator();

    while (records.MoveNext())
    { custInfo.DeleteOnSubmit(records.Current); }

    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I have used `Stopwatch` to look at elapsed time spanning iteration of `records` to completion of `SubmitChanges`. The elapsed times seem to have no rhyme or reason:

10666 records completed in 20 seconds
15425 records completed in 12 seconds
289 records completed in 21 seconds

Obviously, one thing that would speed things up is if I were to drop indexes. Can that be done programmatically? In addition, is there a better method than what I have provided?

Comment: honestly, the most efficient place to find dupes is in the belly of the beast (in the database - stored procedure). i'd be surprised if some requirement on your UI/presentation was to "display duplicates". im guessing this is maintenance?

Comment: Are both sets of records already stored in the database or are the ImportCust records in memory only?

Comment: @RPM1984: yes, after a show & tell with my manager he is writing a SP for this load.

Comment: @Chris: ImportCust is an in-memory DataTable. But this is now changing. I will be pushing ImportCust to a temp table in SqlServer and running a SP for this work.

Comment: @dboarman: That is the absolute best way to handle this.

Comment: @Chris: I couldn't agree more and after my manager saw how this work was slower than molasses in Alaska, he changed his mind about where to put the work. While there are improvements I could make to teh codez, the work efficiency would probably be minimal gains. Like RPM1984 says, keep this work in the belly of the beast.

Comment: Disregard the times on the # of records completed - I was using the StopWatch.Elapsed time a bit wrong...ok, way wrong. Live and learn!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use SQL statment:

```
-- TSQL (SQL Server 2005/2008): --

select CompanyID from tbl_CustomerInfo
    group by CompanyID
    having COUNT(*)>1
```

Answer (score 2):

The linq version of Tefod's sql:

```
from ci in dc.tbl_CustomerInfo
group ci by ci.CompanyID into g
where g.Count() > 1
select g.Key
```

Comment: +1: very nice. I will be able to use this in other projects as well. I seem to have fit in nicely with the "data utilities developer" title.