# Can I disable a table's primary index and re-enable when delete is finished?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-3.5

When I am performing deletes from an Sql table, how would I do the following programmatically?

```
// SqlCommand ???
// do: ALTER TABLE tbl_CustomerInfo DROP CONSTRAINT PK_tbl_CustomerInfo

//   ...perform deletions

// SqlCommand ???
// do: ALTER TABLE tbl_CustomerInfo ADD CONSTRAINT PK_tbl_CustomerInfo PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (RecordID)
```

I guess my question really is can I create an SqlCommand object with these ALTER statements?

#### Update

Here is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454930/is-there-a-more-efficient-method-to-find-dupes-in-sql-server) showing my method for finding the dupe records and then deleting.

Comment: I believe so but I'll wait for an expert... :)

Comment: What are you doing this for?  Because if the deletes reference the primary key, they won't execute as fast as when the index exists.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: this is what we get for not having a DBA to help us out.

Comment: OMG Ponies is the next best thing to having a DBA on staff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user account you are connecting to sql server with has the appropriate rights to issue DDL statements, then yes.

However, I'd consider that a security violation to even allow such a thing.

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275462%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) on how to structure the command.

Comment: +1, but "security violation" might be an odd way to say, "Why on earth would you want to do this from a C# sqlcommand?"

Comment: I would tend to agree on the *security violation* issue. Then again, we don't have any DBA type person here. I have to end up learning SqlServer stuff on the fly as I need it. Not the best, but it's what I have.

Comment: @marr75: Yes and No.  If the app has access to execute DDL statements, then anyone who cracks the app will have access to execute those statements.  Ergo, a security violation.  The user an app executes under should only have the ability to execute those functions that are absolutely necessary.  This is usually normal CRUD statements.